# Using Tweepy and Python, how do I unfollow all the accounts that don't follow me back starting with the oldest ones first?

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

A little help please. This is what I am working with now (I got it from here on stackoverflow) and it works very well, but it seems to only work with the most recent accounts in the list of accounts that don't follow me back. I want to start unfollowing accounts from the oldest to the newest because I keep reaching the limit of the API. I thought to make a list of followers and reverse it then plug that in somewhere but not quite sure how to do that or what the syntax would be. Thanks in advance.

```py
import tweepy

from cred import *
from config import QUERY, UNFOLLOW, FOLLOW, LIKE, RETWEET

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

def main():

    try:
        
        if UNFOLLOW:
            my_screen_name = api.get_user(screen_name='YOUR_SCREEN_NAME')
            for follower in my_screen_name.friends():
                Status = api.get_friendship(source_id = my_screen_name.id , source_screen_name = my_screen_name.screen_name, target_id = follower.id, target_screen_name = follower.screen_name)
                if Status [0].followed_by:
                    print('{} he is following You'.format(follower.screen_name))
                else:
                    print('{} he is not following You'.format(follower.screen_name))
                    api.destroy_friendship(screen_name = follower.screen_name)

    except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
        print(e)


while True:
    main()
```

here is the config.py file

```py
#config.py
UNFOLLOW = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently assembled some pieces of code together to reach this, so I'll just copy paste what I already have here instead of updating your code, but I can point out the main points (and give some tips).
The full code:

```
import tweepy
from cred import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


def unfollower():

    followers = api.get_follower_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
    friends = api.get_friend_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
    print("You follow:", len(friends))    
    
    for friend in friends[::-1]:
        if friend not in followers:
            api.destroy_friendship(user_id = friend)
        else:
            pass
        
    friends = api.friends_ids(screen_name=api.me().screen_name)
    print("Now you're following:", len(friends))

unfollower()
```

Now what happened here and what is different from your code

This two variables:

```
followers = api.followers_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
friends = api.friends_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
```

create a list with the ids from both the followers (follow you) and the friends (you are following), now all we need to do is compare both.

There is a discussion about the Twitter Rate limit and how using cursors have a smaller rate than not using, but I'm not qualified to explain the whys, so let's just assume that if we do not want small rate limits, the best way is not to use requests that have a intrinsic small rate limit like the api.get_friendship and them getting the screen_name, instead I'm using the get_friend_ids method.

the next part involves what you called "make a list of followers and reverse", well the list is already there in the variable "followers", so all we need to do now is reverse read it with the following command:

```
for friend in friends[::-1]:
```

this says: "read each element of the list, starting from index -1" roughtly "read the list backwards".

Well, I think the major points are these, I created a function but you really don't even need to, is just easier to update this to a class if you need to, and this way you don't need to use the while True: main(), just call the function unfollow() and it will automatically end the script when the unfollows are over.

Now some minor points that might improve your code:

Instead of using

```
screen_name='YOUR_SCREEN_NAME'
```

That you need a config file or to hardcode the screen_name, you can use

```
screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name
```

This way it will automatically knows that you want the authenticating user information (note that I didn't used this part on my code, for the get_friend_ids method does not need the screen_name)

Now this part

```
from cred import *
from config import QUERY, UNFOLLOW, FOLLOW, LIKE, RETWEET

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

First I've eliminated the need for the config file
and you can eliminate all the extra info that comes imported from the cred file, so you don't need to import all in from cred import * updating cred.py with:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

and now you can only impor the api function with from cred import api, this way the code can become cleaner:

```
import tweepy
from cred import api

def unfollower():

    followers = api.get_follower_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
    friends = api.get_friend_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
    print("You follow:", len(friends))    
    
    for friend in friends[::-1]:
        if friend not in followers:
            api.destroy_friendship(user_id = friend)
        else:
            pass
        
    friends = api.get_friend_ids(screen_name=api.verify_credentials().screen_name)
    print("Now you're following:", len(friends))

unfollower()
```

Lastly, if anyone is having problems with the api.get_friend_ids or get_follower_ids remember that the tweepy update for [versions 4.x.x](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed the name of some methods, the ones I remember are:

- followers_ids is now get_follower_ids
- friends_ids is now get_friend_ids
- me() is now verify_credentials()

Well, I guest that's it, you can check the rest on the docs.

Happy pythoning!